# Dartdoc could not find any libraries to document

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I am trying to document an api written in Dart with dartdoc.
The dart files i am trying to document are not in a "/lib" folder so when i launch dartdoc at the root of my api i get the following message:

```
Documented 0 libraries in 0.2 seconds.
dartdoc could not find any libraries to document. Run `pub get` and try 
again.
Success! Docs generated into /home...
```

But the only documentation i get is the text written in the readME.md file.

My structure is something like this:

```
/apiRoot
    pubspec.yaml
    ....
    /web
        /controllers
            dartfiles_to_document.dart
            .....
```

I read about official dartdoc documentation and searched there but found no solution to my problem.

I am looking for a way to generate documentation for those dart files.

Comment: I think the files should go into `lib/` instead. I haven't used dartdoc but it's usually a good practice to keep implementation in `lib/` and keeps the `web/main.dart` small.

Comment: I tried this it did'nt work. I think i am doing something wrong, maybe an option to activate with dartdoc or wrong comments in my dart files

Comment: How do you run dartdoc? (exact command line with arguments)

Comment: Did you have the code in `lib/src/...` or just `lib/...` or `lib/foo/...` where `foo` is anything but `src`?

Comment: My code is in the following directory : "/Bureau/upload/globall_software/web/controller"
But i also tried creating a lib folder in controller and putting the dart files in it, without results.

Comment: I just tried it and it worked for me for `lib`. You can try `dartdoc --input="web"`

Comment: I tried and it tells me that there is not pubspec.yaml file in this folder, and if i try to copy the pubspec to this location and relaunch i get the same error.

Comment: you shouldn't need to copy or move `pubspec.yaml`. Sorry, don't know, perhaps someone else.

Comment: As Gunter mentioned, only public API (`lib/`) is documented, not `web/`.

Comment: maybe you were running the command in the wrong path? it just happened to me